# Firebird SQL Query to find a loop in data

Tags: sql, loops, firebird

I am having trouble writing an SQL query to find a data "loop" in my Firebird table.

Its very difficult to explain the situation so I will rather give an example:

```
Table: Explosion    

Stockcode   | IngredientStockcode
----------------------------------
001         | 010 
001         | 011
001         | 012

010         | 011
010         | 013
010         | 014    

012         | 013
012         | 015
012         | 001 <-- This causes a loop in my data. Stockcode 001 has an 
                      ingredient of 012 and stockcode 012 has 001 as 
                      an ingredient.

013         | 014
013         | 015
013         | 001 <-- This also causes a loop in my data. 013 is part of (an
                      ingredient of) 010. 010 is also an ingredient of 001. 001
                      cannot then also be an ingredient of 013.
```

I need to write a query to identify these "loops" in the data. Any help would be appreciated.

This should be a complex query with joins. I have already tried something like this below and I think I might be on the right track..

```
select * FROM explosion x1
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM Explosion x2
               where exists ( SELECT 1 FROM Explosion x3 where
                              x3.ingredientStockcode = x1.Stockcode
                              AND x1.RDB$DB_KEY < x3.RDB$DB_KEY)
and x1.ingredientStockcode = x2.Stockcode
AND x1.RDB$DB_KEY < x2.RDB$DB_KEY)
```

Comment: @Delpiguy: IF you have a way to determine the **prime materials** in your stock, you can quickly check with a recursive query, but it is not clear, from what you post if you have a way in your structure to determine this in a query, not from the shown explosion table.

Answer (score 2):

You have a typical graph/tree problem here.

I'm afraid that one single query won't solve your issue. You'll need a loop to traverse each tree.

But you have another problem, you can't easily select the root nodes. So you will either need to mark the root nodes or traverse your trees bottom up (so beginning with the basic ingredients that have no further ingredients).

The second option is more natural for this kind of data because something is always usable to create something more complex.

You can search google for algoritmes for trees in SQL.

Success

Comment: It CAN be solved easily in one query using a CTE, but I don't know if Firebird supports them

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the firebird SQL syntax, but this generic SQL Query shold help you:

```
select *  
from Explosion e1
inner join Explosion e2 
        on e1.Stockcode = e2.IngredientStockcode
       and e1.IngredientStockcode = e2.Stockcode
```

**EDIT**

Had a quick check, and the documentation seems to suggest the above will work. However, just in case, an alternative syntax is:

```
select *  
  from Explosion e1, Explosion e2
 where e1.Stockcode = e2.IngredientStockcode
   and e1.IngredientStockcode = e2.Stockcode
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply James, but this does not work. 
    
e1.Stockcode = e2.IngredientStockcode and 
e2.IngredientStockcode = e1.Stockcode 
is exactly the same statement.

Comment: Sorry, got it muddled. Swap the e2 and e1 on the last line

Comment: I verified this quickly on the sql server and it does give you the looping records. That is 2 records for each loop of course.

Comment: Yes. That is the correct way to do it on SQL Server. I can only assume there is something different required for firebird sql

Comment: Well how many levels of recursion do you want to track for the loops? The query itself does only go one level deep...

Comment: Using the test data (as described above) and your second SQL query (firebird syntax) I do get 2 records returned indicating the first loop correctly. The second loop however is not returned. I need to go a few levels deep. Can this query be adjusted to allow me to go 2,3+ levels deep?